How to return the correct dependent type?
Studying the application of dependent types I've found the definition below for dependent vectors.
Inductive vector(A: Type): nat -> Type :=
  empty_vector: vector A 0
  | nonempty_vector: forall (n: nat), A -> vector A n -> vector A (S n).

I wish to write functions that return the same type vectors as the input vector.
This very simple one works fine:
Definition fnc1(n: nat) (v: vector bool n): Type :=
vector bool n.

However, specifying the return type as vector bool n yields an error:
Definition fnc2(n: nat) (v: vector bool n): vector bool n :=
vector bool n.

In environment
n : nat
v : vector bool n
The term "vector bool n" has type "Set"
while it is expected to have type "vector bool n".

Now this one is also fine:
Definition fnc3(n: nat) (v: vector bool n): vector bool n :=
v.

What is wrong with fnc2?
Thank you.

it is your := vector bool n code that looks off. Indeed, you cannot use vector bool n for both the return type and the return value! More generally, we cannot have T : T for the same expression T.

@ErikMD thanks for your reply. Any suggestion how to return a bool vector of length n then?

As mentioned in the comments: the culprit is your := vector bool n code as you cannot use vector bool n for both the return type and the return value. More generally, we cannot have T : T for the same expression T.
If you want to build a value having type vector bool n (which is an inductive type with two constructors), you can just use the constructors:
Definition example1 := @nonempty_vector bool 1 true (@nonempty_vector bool 0 true (@empty_vector bool)).

You can also use pattern-matching + a Fixpoint (recursive function) over another inductive type such as nat, to build e.g. a "constant vector".
Namely:
Set Implicit Arguments.

Inductive vector(A: Type): nat -> Type :=
  empty_vector: vector A 0
| nonempty_vector: forall (n: nat), A -> vector A n -> vector A (S n).

Fixpoint const_n (b : bool) (n : nat) : vector bool n :=
  match n with
  | 0 => empty_vector bool
  | S p => nonempty_vector b (const_n b p)
  end.

Eval compute in const_n true 2.
(* = nonempty_vector true (nonempty_vector true (empty_vector bool))
   : vector bool 2
 *)

Disclaimer: while vectors defined this way are a simple/useful example to start learning with dependent types, they are actually not recommended to use in production as there are more successful approaches to formalize them in Coq. See e.g. the comments in:

https://coq.inria.fr/doc/V8.20.0/stdlib/Coq.Vectors.Vector.html
https://coq.inria.fr/doc/V8.20.0/stdlib/Coq.Vectors.VectorDef.html


Thank you for your kind help, Erik. I did try to construct the return vector in a similar way as in your code but then another error occurred due to the lack of the  Set Implicit Arguments line.

Yes, this line should generally be used at the beginning of the file when one defines polymorphic types. To sum up, nonempty_vector true n v is then seen as @nonempty_vector _ true n v where the _ refers to the type that can be inferred (here, it is the type of true). For details: https://coq.inria.fr/doc/master/refman/language/extensions/implicit-arguments.html
